# GROUP BY clause with non aggregate functions

Tags: mysql

Why mysql allows use non aggregate functions with `GROUP BY` clause ?

For example, this query works fine:

```
SELECT col, CHAR_LENGTH(col) FROM table
GROUP BY col
```

There is acceptable using querys like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes is quite acceptable. Your query, written in more standard SQL, would be something like:

```
SELECT col, CHAR_LENGTH(col)
FROM (SELECT col FROM table GROUP BY col) c
```

or as:

```
SELECT col, MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(col))
FROM table
GROUP BY col
```

using non aggregate functions you can simplify the query a little bit, but the query would be a little more difficult to read.

It could also be useful when you are sure that all non aggregated columns share the same value:

```
SELECT id, name, surname
FROM table
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*)=1
```

or when it doesn't matter which value you need to return:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM table
GROUP BY id
```

will return a single name associated to that id (probably the first name encountered, but we can't be sure which one is the first, order by doesn't help here...). Be warned that if you want to select multiple non aggregated columns:

```
SELECT id, name, surname
FROM table
GROUP BY id
```

we have no guarantees that the name and surname returned will belong to the same row.

I would prefer not to use this extension, unless you are 100% sure of why you are using it.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has some "improvements" and tries to run and return result from invalid queries, in example like yours every good RDBMS should throw syntax error, but MySQL will run it, group the result by col and put value of randomly chosen row into second column.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm guessing correctly about what you want to do, `DISTINCT` is a better choice:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col, CHAR_LENGTH(col) FROM table;
```

It more clearly indicates the readers what you're trying to accomplish.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c511b3/1/0) is a SQLFiddle.